# access 2010 recursive data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm more than a novice with Access 2010 but certainly not an expert. I work with Access on a daily basis yet this problem stumps me.

I have a table that I need to query to retrieve a set of Groups, subgroups and all possible sub-members.
The table is laid out as:

Desired GROUP | CURRENT TN | SPRINT TELEPHONE NUMBER | LAST NAME | FIRST NAME
5553215255 | 5553210001 | 4143210009 | Weir Bob
5553215255 | 5553210002 | 4143210008 | Garcia Jerry
5553215255 |5553210003 | 4143210007 | Hendrix Jimi
5553215255 | 5553210004 | 4143210006 | Peds Page
5553210004 | 3144230009 | 4143210005 | Cash Johnny
5553210004 | 3144230008 | 4143210003 | Morrison Jim
5553210004 | 3144230007 | 4143210002 |Beethoven Ludwig
5553210004 | 3144230911 | 4143210001 | Emergency Peds Page
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210099 |Strummer Joe
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210098 | Mercury Freddie
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210097 |Presley Elvis
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210096 | Bopper Big

Fields Defined:

- Desired GROUP: a group of people based on a role or other criteria. This number when paged will send a page to the Members of a given group.
- Current TN: The telephone of a given member. A member can be a person or a Desired GROUP
- Sprint Telephone Number: Some people will be replacing their pager with a Sprint phone.
- Last Name: Role or Last name of a person. Sometimes a group name or similar.
- First Name: First name of a person

I need a query that when run returns a list of all members of all groups paged.
Suppose I Send a page to Doctors. Paging Doctors also pages all members of Peds, which in turn pages all members of Emergency Peds The result would show the ALL members of Doctors, ALL members of Peds (EXCEPT GROUP NAMES), and ALL Members of Emergency Peds who were paged as a result of the initial page. Notice Peds Page and Emergency Peds Page were left out. Illustrated here:

Desired GROUP | CURRENT TN | SPRINT TELEPHONE NUMBER | LAST NAME | FIRST NAME
5553215255 | 5553210001 | 4143210009 | Weir Bob
5553215255 | 5553210002 | 4143210008 | Garcia Jerry
5553215255 |5553210003 | 4143210007 | Hendrix Jimi
5553210004 | 3144230009 | 4143210005 | Cash Johnny
5553210004 | 3144230008 | 4143210003 | Morrison Jim
5553210004 | 3144230007 | 4143210002 |Beethoven Ludwig
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210099 |Strummer Joe
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210098 | Mercury Freddie
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210097 |Presley Elvis
3144230911 | 6362341101 | 4143210096 | Bopper Big

1. One co-worker suggests querying by hand multiple times, saving the results into multiple tables and then appending all the resulting tables into one table. How do I do this? It seems this is a solution I would understand easily at my level but I'm not quite getting it, try as I might.
2. Is there another way besides the above solution?
3. Is there anything else I need to know if I will be comparing a second similar table to the first? MEMBERS of the second may be GROUP LEADS in the first.

MIGHTY BIG thanks in advance.

---

Edit to include sql from comments.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT tbl_group_build.[desired group],tbl_group_build.[current tn], 
                   tbl_group_build.[sprint telephone number], 
                   tbl_group_build.[last name], 
                   tbl_group_build.[first name] 
    FROM   tbl_group_build 
    UNION 
    SELECT tbl_Group_build_1.[desired group],tbl_Group_build_1.[current tn], 
           tbl_Group_build_1.[sprint telephone number], 
           tbl_Group_build_1.[last name],tbl_Group_build_1.[first name] 
    FROM   tbl_group_build 
           INNER JOIN tbl_group_build AS tbl_Group_build_1 
                   ON tbl_group_build.[current tn] = 
                      tbl_Group_build_1.[desired group] 
    UNION 
    SELECT tbl_Group_build_2.[desired group],tbl_Group_build_2.[current tn], 
           tbl_Group_build_2.[sprint telephone number], 
           tbl_Group_build_2.[last name],tbl_Group_build_2.[first name] 
    FROM   (tbl_group_build 
            INNER JOIN tbl_group_build AS tbl_Group_build_1 
                    ON tbl_group_build.[current tn] = 
                       tbl_Group_build_1.[desired group]) 
           INNER JOIN tbl_group_build AS tbl_Group_build_2 
                   ON tbl_Group_build_1.[current tn] = 
                      tbl_Group_build_2.[desired group]) g
```

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? Your explanation is overly complicated and I'm not sure what you're actually looking to get as a result of the query. Wouldn't it make more sense to just return everything at once? Also if this is really a table instead of a query, you should look into normalizing it.

Comment: Agreed on normalizing but we're past that point, unfortunately. I've been told not to worry about that at this point.

Comment: Is there a separate table that indicates what groups were paged? Are members part of multiple groups? Is there any way to know what the sub groups are based upon the data in your database?

Comment: Agreed on normalizing but we're past that point, unfortunately. I've been told not to worry about that at this point. As for as what I'm trying to achieve: assume I sent a page to the Doctors group lead number. From there it sends a page to the Doctors in that group and to Peds Page which is the Lead for yet another group. Peds Page then pages all of its members which includes the Emergency Peds Page number which is the lead number for Emergency Peds. My boss wants to see the final result that looks similar to the second table example (which I'll clean up right now).

Comment: ALL leads are in the GROUP NUMBER column. Some in the Member TN are some of those same leads. There are no leads in the MEMBER TN column that are not in the GROUP NUMBER column.

I've tried a "SELF-JOIN" and also copying my original table and joining LEAD NUMBER from the original to MEMBER TN on the copy. If I pull all fields from one of the tables down to the grid I get a duplicate of the original set. So apparently I'm not pulling down the right fields from the right tables.

Comment: btw, thanks for your help and comments.

Comment: Further clarification: ideally if using the query and append method, for example, my query would show which numbers in the MEMBER TN happen to be leads and the numbers they page. Then that set would be appended to the original set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the start of an idea. I noticed that in the sample data, the telephone number of group lead is the same as the telephone number of the page. There would be other possible joins, but this is by far the cleanest.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT groups.group_name, 
               groups.[group_lead member], 
               groups.tn, 
               groups.last_name, 
               groups.first_name 
        FROM   groups 
        WHERE  groups.group_name = [enter page] 
        UNION 
        SELECT Groups_1.group_name, 
               Groups_1.[group_lead member], 
               Groups_1.tn, 
               Groups_1.last_name, 
               Groups_1.first_name 
        FROM   groups 
               INNER JOIN groups AS Groups_1 
                       ON groups.tn = Groups_1.[group_lead member] 
        UNION 
        SELECT Groups_2.group_name, 
               Groups_2.[group_lead member], 
               Groups_2.tn, 
               Groups_2.last_name, 
               Groups_2.first_name 
        FROM   (groups 
                INNER JOIN groups AS Groups_1 
                        ON groups.tn = Groups_1.[group_lead member]) 
               INNER JOIN groups AS Groups_2 
                       ON Groups_1.tn = Groups_2.[group_lead member]) g 
WHERE  Trim(Replace([last_name], "page", "")) 
       NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT group_name FROM groups)
```

---

New data

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT groups.[desired group],groups.[current tn], 
                       groups.[sprint telephone number], 
                       groups.[last name],groups.[first name] 
        FROM   groups 
        WHERE  groups.[desired group] = [enter desired group] 
        UNION 
        SELECT Groups_1.[desired group],Groups_1.[current tn], 
               Groups_1.[sprint telephone number],Groups_1.[last name], 
               Groups_1.[first name] 
        FROM   groups 
               INNER JOIN groups AS Groups_1 
                       ON groups.[current tn] = Groups_1.[desired group] 
        UNION 
        SELECT Groups_2.[desired group],Groups_2.[current tn], 
               Groups_2.[sprint telephone number],Groups_2.[last name], 
               Groups_2.[first name] 
        FROM   (groups 
                INNER JOIN groups AS Groups_1 
                        ON groups.[current tn] = Groups_1.[desired group]) 
               INNER JOIN groups AS Groups_2 
                       ON Groups_1.[current tn] = Groups_2.[desired group]) AS g 
WHERE  g.[last name] NOT IN (SELECT [last name] 
                                    FROM   groups 
                                    WHERE  [current tn] IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                           [desired group] 
                                                            FROM   groups))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This looks like a great lead.
I accidentally included the GROUP_NAME when it's not really there(it's in another table I have). So I have the group_lead, member_tn, last_name, and first_name. I'm trying to edit your code accordingly. But am getting stuck on the first where statement. How should I edit that accordingly?

Comment: You can't. A chunk of the logic depends on Group_Name. Create a query called Groups, to match the above name, and include the table with Group_Name and the one with the other data so your query matches the sample data you posted. You should then be able to run the above "as is".

Comment: I tried editing but just got back the initial results set. I Edited for my real table names etc. that I initially changed for simplification of my example (which looks like I actually complicated things.) I won't be using the table with group_name in this work. It's for a different part of my task and though it's similar data doesn't apply here. I'll try to add my code in the next comment. Thanks again.

Comment: I suppose I could copy my table to a table called groups and temporarily add a column called group_name and just auto-populate it with the lead_tn since we use them interchangeably anyway. Then I should be able to use your code as is.

Comment: Usually the best thing to do is to post sample data that relates to your problem :) I am somewhat lost as to what your table contains, so until I see some new data I am stuck. I do not see why you cannot create a simple query that joins the group names table to this table. if you can create a new table, why can't you create a query?

Comment: Consider my simplifying my table/data a stackoverflow newbie error. I should have used real data then changed names and numbers since they're confidential. I'll clarify a little. Table name will be Groups to match your code. The columns are Desired Group which a Group Pager number that sends pages to a whole group at a time; CURRENT TN is the pager a person currently has; Sprint TN is the phone number of the sprint device that will replace that pager. NAME fields are just that descriptors but you get the idea. I'll try to copy my table to one called groups and then using your query as is.

Comment: Just edit your question to include real field names for the two tables and imaginary, but relevant data. So if the telephone number for Bob is 123 and the telephone number for Peds is 123, make sure that you include the match, but not, obviously, the real number.

Comment: Question edited to reflect real table. Desired GROUP as mentioned earlier should work just the same as the earlier used group_name.

Comment: It is much easier for me to communicate with sample data. For instance, there are all those terrible spaces in the field names.

Comment: This just might be doing the trick! Thanks for all your help. I owe you big! Not just a beer but a meal too! Thanks so very much!

Comment: I'm not as fan of a lot of what's wrong with out table including spaces and all. I'm slowly converting what I can of all the data I've inherited and being sure to eliminate spaces in field and table names I create. Thanks for all the tips.

Comment: Yep, it is a pain inheriting data. However, it does not look like the worst you could get. And you are welcome.